# Angular 7 server response not showing in list

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular7

I am very newbie on Angular. Currently I started working one sample. I am trying to get data from server and would like to show same in list. API response is coming in postman but it's not happening in code.

I am trying from since 2 days but no luck. Please provide me any reference or hint. Here is my code:
home.component.ts :

```
export class HomeComponent {
    currentUser: User;
    companiesFromAPI: Companies;

    constructor(
        private userService: UserService,
        private authenticationService: AuthenticationService
    ) {
        this.currentUser = this.authenticationService.currentUserValue;
        console.log(this.currentUser.token)
        if(this.currentUser.role === "Admin"){

        } else if(this.currentUser.role === "User"){
          console.log("In user");

          this.userService.getCompaniesById(this.currentUser.id).subscribe(
            data => this.companiesFromAPI = data as Companies
          );
        }
    }
```

userService.ts :

```
getCompaniesById(id) {
    return this.http.get('http://www.localhost:8080/omshreess_webservices/get_companies_by_user.php?id='+id);
  }
```

companies.ts .

```
export class Companies {
status: number;
companies: Company[];
}

interface Company {
tbl_company_master_id: string;
file_number: string;
company_name: string;
added_at: string;
updated_at: string;
address_first_line: string;
address_second_line: string;
pf_code: string;
cmp_pf_rate_contri: string;
cmp_pension_rate_contri: string;
ac2: string;
ac21: string;
ac22: string;
retirment_age: string;
cmp_pension_salary_limit: string;
cmp_pf_salary_limit: string;
esic_code: string;
esi_sal_limit: string;
esic_employee_rate: string;
local_office: string;
bank_name: string;
bank_address: string;
ot_rate: string;
pt_registration_number: string;
year: string;
user_id: string;
Pf_company_user_id: string;
Pf_company_password: string;
esic_user_id: string;
esic_password: string;
pt_user_id: string;
pt_password: string;
contact_person_name: string;
contact_person_number: string;
contact_person_email: string;
field_1: string;
field_2: string;
field_3: string;
}
```

home.component.html .

```
<ul>
    <li *ngIf="companiesFromAPI">{{companiesFromAPI.company_name}} {{companiesFromAPI.file_number}}</li>
</ul> .
```

Here is json response which I am getting now. :

```
{
"status": 0,
"companies": [
    {
        "tbl_company_master_id": "3",
        "file_number": "1",
        "company_name": "Armal Apps",
        "added_at": "2019-04-14 17:37:10",
        "updated_at": "2019-04-14 17:37:10",
        "address_first_line": "Chinchwad",
        "address_second_line": "Pune",
        "pf_code": "123456Adg",
        "cmp_pf_rate_contri": "12",
        "cmp_pension_rate_contri": "4",
        "ac2": "123",
        "ac21": "123",
        "ac22": "123",
        "retirment_age": "50",
        "cmp_pension_salary_limit": "4000",
        "cmp_pf_salary_limit": "5000",
        "esic_code": "12345",
        "esi_sal_limit": "3000",
        "esic_employee_rate": "12",
        "local_office": "pune",
        "bank_name": "HDFC",
        "bank_address": "Pune",
        "ot_rate": "2",
        "pt_registration_number": "bd6282bk",
        "year": "2019",
        "user_id": "2",
        "Pf_company_user_id": "san",
        "Pf_company_password": "san",
        "esic_user_id": "san",
        "esic_password": "san",
        "pt_user_id": "san",
        "pt_password": "san",
        "contact_person_name": "san",
        "contact_person_number": "8698579562",
        "contact_person_email": "armalsandip@gmail.com",
        "field_1": "1",
        "field_2": "1",
        "field_3": "1"
    },
    {
        "tbl_company_master_id": "4",
        "file_number": "2",
        "company_name": "Infosys",
        "added_at": "2019-04-14 17:38:10",
        "updated_at": "2019-04-14 17:38:10",
        "address_first_line": "Chinchwad",
        "address_second_line": "Pune",
        "pf_code": "bfsanb2b4",
        "cmp_pf_rate_contri": "12",
        "cmp_pension_rate_contri": "4",
        "ac2": "123",
        "ac21": "123",
        "ac22": "123",
        "retirment_age": "50",
        "cmp_pension_salary_limit": "4000",
        "cmp_pf_salary_limit": "5000",
        "esic_code": "12345",
        "esi_sal_limit": "3000",
        "esic_employee_rate": "12",
        "local_office": "pune",
        "bank_name": "HDFC",
        "bank_address": "Pune",
        "ot_rate": "2",
        "pt_registration_number": "bd6282bk",
        "year": "2019",
        "user_id": "2",
        "Pf_company_user_id": "san",
        "Pf_company_password": "san",
        "esic_user_id": "san",
        "esic_password": "san",
        "pt_user_id": "san",
        "pt_password": "san",
        "contact_person_name": "san",
        "contact_person_number": "8698579562",
        "contact_person_email": "armalsandip@gmail.com",
        "field_1": "1",
        "field_2": "1",
        "field_3": "1"
    }
]
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to display a list. So, you must use *ngFor for iterating through the array. Here's what you can do to make it work:

```
<ul *ngIf='companiesFromAPI'>
  <li *ngFor='let cmpy of companiesFromAPI.companies'>{{cmpy.company_name}}</li>
</ul>
```